# Failed to fetch: Js code on Html template

Tags: javascript, html, django

In a JS code I'm using fetch to make GET requests to a url to obtain data in JSON format. The js code is located in my Django project and I use it in some templates. When I click on the button that activates the js script, it tells me that there is an error in the fetch, can someone help me?

```
function iniciarEscaneo() {
// Mostrar el mensaje de escaneo en progreso
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText = "Escaneando NFC...";
document.getElementById("mensaje").style.display = "block";

// Establecer tiempo límite de espera en 10 segundos (10000 milisegundos)
var tiempoLimite = 10000;

// Realizar la solicitud GET a la URL para obtener el NFC
fetch("http://192.168.0.23:8081/read_nfc")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Procesar la respuesta JSON
        if (data && data.uid) {
            // Actualizar el campo UID NFC en la plantilla con el UID obtenido
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText = "NFC leído correctamente.";
            document.getElementById("id_uid_nfc").innerText = data.uid;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText = "No se pudo leer el NFC.";
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al obtener el NFC:', error);
        document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText = "Error al obtener el NFC: " + error.message;
    })
    .finally(() => {
        // Ocultar el mensaje después de un breve período de tiempo
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText === "Escaneando NFC...") {
                document.getElementById("mensaje").innerText = "Tiempo de espera excedido. Intenta nuevamente.";
            }
            document.getElementById("mensaje").style.display = "none";
        }, tiempoLimite);
    });
```

}

I have tried to solve it by allowing cross origin but nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To be able to help you with this problem, we need to see your `fetch` command and the error you see. Without these components it is impossible to guess what exactly happens on your side.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added the code

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add the text of the error that you see? Also, what do you see if you navigate to http://192.168.0.23:8081/read_nfc just in your browser?

Comment: The message that i get is "Error al obtener el NFC: failed to fetch", and the url is a server that is running on an esp32 with micropython. The url starts the NFC reader and results in the UID of the NFC tag in JSON format.

Comment: What do you see if you open http://192.168.0.23:8081/read_nfc with your browser, ideally from the same machine where you ran this code?

Comment: When I enter the url with my browser, it waits for the NFC to be read and when it is detected, the information appears in JSON format.

Comment: Try running the same fetch but with the opened Network tab in the Developer Tools and checking how the network request looks, how the response was returned, if it has HTTP status code 200, and if the returned content looks as expected.